# Local declaration hides instance variable - property and synthesize

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

**update 0**

Do you mean to change all of the `deals` to `_deals` and all the `iboards` to `_iboards` and add the following method and then call it at the end of the `processPbn` method? If so, what does the call look like?

```
- (id)initWithName:(NSInteger )_iboard deals:(NSArray *)_deals
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
       iboard = _iboard;
        deals = _deals;
        return self;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

**update 0**

I want to make the 2 variables `deals` and `iboards`, which are computed in `BSViewcontroller`, available for use in `BSdealViewController`. I am getting the following two Semantic Issues in the code at the end (**the last 3 lines**) of BSViewController.m .

```
"Local declaration of 'deals' hides instance variable"
"Local declaration of 'iboards' hides instance variable"
```

BSViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface BSViewController : UIViewController <....>
        {
            NSInteger iboard;
            NSArray *deals;
            }
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger iboard;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *deals;
- (void) processPbn;
@end
```

BSViewController.m

```
#import "BSViewController.h"
@interface BSViewController ()

@end
@implementation BSViewController
@synthesize iboard, deals;

- (void) processPbn
{
    NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest .....];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:theRequest queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *connection, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
         NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
         NSString *sp = @"             ";
         NSArray*deals=@[[@[sp, sp, sp, sp]mutableCopy],[@[sp, sp, sp, sp]mutableCopy],[@[sp, sp, sp, sp]mutableCopy],[@[sp, sp, sp, sp]mutableCopy],[@[sp, sp, sp, sp]mutableCopy],[@[sp, sp, sp, sp]mutableCopy]];

         NSString *toMatch = @"...";

         int iboard = 0;
         NSRegularExpression *regex = [....];
         NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [....];
         for (NSTextCheckingResult* board in [.....])
         {
             for (NSUInteger irange = 1; irange < board.numberOfRanges; ++irange)
             {
                 NSRange matchedRange = [board rangeAtIndex: irange];
                 NSString* tstring = [string substringWithRange: matchedRange];
                 for (NSUInteger ix = 0; ix < tstring.length; ++ix)
                 {
                     NSRange cardInSuit = NSMakeRange(ix, 1);
                     int seat = (irange-1)/4 ;
                     int suit = (irange-1)%4 ;
                     NSString* replace= [deals[iboard][suit] ....];
                     [deals[iboard] replaceObjectAtIndex: suit withObject: replace];
                 }
             }
             ++iboard;
         }
     }];
}

@end
```

(As a result of the above?) I am also getting the error `Use of undeclared identifier 'iboard'` in the NSLog instruction below.

BSdealViewController.m

```
#import "BSdealViewController.h"
#import "BSViewController.h"

@interface BSdealViewController ()

@end
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"iboard : %@", iboard);
}
```

Comment: I think it must be eclaration of **'deal'** hides instance , rather than **deals**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> "Local declaration of 'deals' hides instance variable"
> "Local declaration of 'iboard' hides instance variable"
> ```

You have variable named `deals` in your method that is a collision with ivar having same name.

> NSString *toMatch = @"...";
>
> ```
>      int iboard = 0;
>          ^^^^^^
>
>      NSRegularExpression *regex = [....];
> ```

Also,

```
NSString *sp = @"             ";
NSArray*deals=@[[@[sp, sp, sp, sp]mutableCopy],[@[sp, sp, sp, sp]mutableCopy],[@[sp, sp, sp, sp]mutableCopy],[@[sp, sp, sp, sp]mutableCopy],[@[sp, sp, sp, sp]mutableCopy],[@[sp, sp, sp, sp]mutableCopy]];
        ^^^^^
```

Change the variable in the method name to `aDeals` and `aIboards` or something that is different from ivars.

Comment: I don't understand. `iboard` and `deals` contain the values I want. How do I make those values available in the BSdealViewController class if I change their names?

Comment: @zeroWords this is precisely why iVars complicate your life.  Prefix both of those with underscores, then make the appropriate changes.  Or, convert them to properties.

Comment: You have got 2 variables having same name. change either one. And I prefer to change the local one.

Comment: @CodaFi, What are "the appropriate changes"? I am lost.

Comment: `change all of the deals to _deals` is one way to do and that is a convention. You must have seen some code where aTableView is used. You can use any other word as aDeals, passDeals, paraDeals etc.

Comment: In the apple BirdWatching example in `BirdsDetailViewController.h'` there is `@property (strong, nonatomic) BirdSighting *sighting;` and in `BirdsDetailViewController.m` there is  `- (void)setSighting:(BirdSighting *) newSighting` which says, for example, `_sighting = newSighting;`. By analogy, is that what you mean? I am unsure because BirdWatching has a separate "data" class named `BirdSighting` and I have no separate "data" class so I don't quite see the analogy, if there is one, because `BirdSighting` contains all the ivars in one init style method.

Comment: My app does not have a separate method containing both `deals` and `iboard` only. I understand the `setSighting` method is a setter, but is it considered an ivar setter even though it is in the receiving class, not the constructing class?

Comment: `BirdsDetailViewControlle`r class contains a property `sighting`. And in your case your current class contains `deals`. so there is a name collision between class' deals and yuor method's deals. This should be unique.

Comment: if u still have doubts you can mail me your app to my mail id. I will check and try to solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the offer Annop, but no. In my `update 0` to the question I have added a method `initWithName:`. But I don't know how or where/when to execute that method. I thought that it should be used something like `BSViewController *bsview =[self initWithName:(NSInteger )_iboard deals:(NSArray *)_deals];` in side BSViewController.m's `viewDidLoad`, but does `viewDidLoad` execute to early? And once `bsview` is defined correctly, then is it accessed as a property of imported BSViewController in BSdealViewController.m?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the convention used by most experienced developers that you should follow:

Use properties when possible, for example a property "iboard" and a property "deals". 
Use instance variables with a leading underscore, like "_iboard" and "_deals".

Do NOT use a leading underscore anywhere else.

This way anyone reading your source code can spot the use of instance variables from a mile away, and you cannot accidentally use an instance variable when you meant to use a property. Your init method should be

```
- (id)initWithIBoard:(NSInteger )iboard deals:(NSArray *)deals
{
    if ((self = [super init]) != nil)
    {
        _iboard = iboard;
        _deals = deals;
    }

    return self;
}
```